# AngularJS : multiple promise wait all

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a little question about multiple promise. 
How can I wait that all promises will be done for return the final result.

See my code :

```
getInfo : function(){
        return promiseA.then(function(result){
               info  = result;
               //this function have also promises 
               return ServiceA.functionA(info.login)
                      .then(function(favouriteItems){
                          info.favorites = favouriteItems;
                          return $q.when(info);
                       });      
         });       
},
```

My aims it's to wait the result of ServiceA.functionA before return value.

Thanks

K.L

Comment: Use [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).

Comment: In this situation impossible to use $q.all(), because function ServiceA.functionA need to use result of promiseA.

Comment: It looks to me like you already are. The promise returned by `getInfo` will be resolved with `info` after its `favorites` item has been modified in the final callback.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$q.all()`

This is a good post here on the question: [stackoverflow.com/questions/21310964/angularjs-q-all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310964/angularjs-q-all)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an answer to another question stating the solution to this problem using the $q.all approach.

Check it out: [AngularJS: Listen to events, one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590772/angularjs-listen-to-events-one-after-the-other/22591241#22591241)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getInfo() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  promiseA.then(function(result){
    info  = result;
    // this function have also promises 
    ServiceA.functionA(info.login)
      .then(function(favouriteItems){
         info.favorites = favouriteItems;
           // the magic
           deferred.resolve(info);
           // at this point, you can resolve any value
      });      
    });
  }

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

then later you can call that function and get a promise...

```
var promise = getInfo();
promise.then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback);
```

The `successCallback` will only be called once `resolve` has been called on the deferred object.

Comment: you manually call it with `$q.reject(reason)` in the error callbacks of the other requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
getInfo : function() {
  return promiseA.then(function(result){           
    return ServiceA.functionA(result.login).then(function(favouriteItems){
      result.favorites = favouriteItems;
      return result;
    });      
  });       
},
```

Use like this:

```
api.getInfo().then(function(result){
  // use result and result.favorites
}, function(err){
  // here you can be if an error occurred in promiseA or in ServiceA.functionA
})
```

Comment: It is always encouraged to give at least a little explanation what your code is doing.